# How to read comment blocks in PHP?

Tags: php, reflection, comments

I'm doing some home-brewed automated documentation, since I have a codebase which is not very standard in its layout, and I was wondering what the best way was to read a PHP file and grab the contents of a comment block. The only way I can think to do it is to open the file and read it line-by-line, but thought that maybe there was some built-in magic that would parse the document for me, similar to the Reflection functions.

The basic layout of each file is like this:

```
<?php // $Id$
/**
 * Here is this script's documentation, with information in pseudo-javadoc
 * type tags and whatnot.
 *
 * @attr    something    some information about something
 * @attr    etc          etc etc
 */
 // rest of the code goes here.
```

It's important to note that these files don't have any functions or classes defined in them. The comments relate to the script as a whole.

Comment: I think this answer may help [Read comments block from file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3228978/php-read-file-comments-not-file-content-forgotten/36688259#36688259)

Answer (score 17):

Check out [Tokenizer](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.tokenizer.php).

To get all the comments in a file named `test.php` you'd do:

```
$tokens = token_get_all(file_get_contents("test.php"));
$comments = array();
foreach($tokens as $token) {
    if($token[0] == T_COMMENT || $token[0] == T_DOC_COMMENT) {
        $comments[] = $token[1];
    }
}
print_r($comments);
```

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at the [Reflection API](http://www.php.net/language.oop5.reflection) that comes with PHP5, more specifically `getDocComment()`:

> PHP 5 comes with a complete reflection
>   API that adds the ability to
>   reverse-engineer classes, interfaces,
>   functions and methods as well as
>   extensions. Additionally, the
>   reflection API also offers ways of
>   retrieving doc comments for functions,
>   classes and methods.

Also, depending on the size of your codebase, you might work less by modifying your comments to fit the [phpDocumentor](http://www.phpdoc.org/) syntax, which is already seems pretty close to.

Comment: it really is a very strange layout and requires a very specific output I'm afraid. The reflection functions seems to only apply to functions, classes, objects, etc. Can you pass it a file to parse?

Comment: +1 phpDocumentor, especially if the code is already formatter for it.