# Read file comments in PHP, NOT file content - forgotten

Tags: php, comments

I need to read the first "batch" of comment in a PHP file. An example would be:

```
<?php
/** This is some basic file info **/
?>
<?php This is the "file" proper" ?>
```

I need to read the first comment inside another file, but how do I get the `/** This is some basic file info **/` as a string?

Comment: `<?php "\/** t **\/" ?>` ? I don't actually know, but that would be the first thing I'd try

Comment: Thnk Mechko, but somewhere in the dim and distant past I found a function to do it - can't remember if it's a 'php function' or a custom written one

Answer (score 17, accepted):

There's a `token_get_all($code)` function which can be used for this and it's more reliable than you first might think.

Here's some example code to get all comments out of a file (it's untested, but should be enough to get you started):

```
<?php

    $source = file_get_contents( "file.php" );

    $tokens = token_get_all( $source );
    $comment = array(
        T_COMMENT,      // All comments since PHP5
        T_ML_COMMENT,   // Multiline comments PHP4 only
        T_DOC_COMMENT   // PHPDoc comments      
    );
    foreach( $tokens as $token ) {
        if( !in_array($token[0], $comment) )
            continue;
        // Do something with the comment
        $txt = $token[1];
    }

?>
```

Comment: Hey I would change this only a little bit... change the `break` to a `continue` so that you can continue to find all the comments in the contents.

Comment: As suggested by @CayceK, I've changed the `break` to a `continue`.

Comment: @davewoodhall sadly it won't keep. The "change" queue for all questions will deny you every time. It is only a small change and is up to the user of the code to make that change. Your effort is noted though!

Comment: Hey guys, that was clearly an error in my code, so I did the edit. Sorry, didn't bother before, as the answer is already some years old ;).

Answer (score 1):

I think you can also try this:

```
/**
* Return first doc comment found in this file.
*
* @return string
*/
function getFileCommentBlock($file_name)
{
    $Comments = array_filter(
            token_get_all(file_get_contents($file_name)), function($entry) {
                return $entry[0] == T_DOC_COMMENT;
            }
        );

    $fileComment = array_shift($Comments);
    return $fileComment[1];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you mean?

```
$file_contents = '/**

sd
asdsa
das
sa
das
sa
a
ad**/';

preg_match('#/\*\*(.*)\*\*/#s', $file_contents, $matches);

var_dump($matches);
```

Comment: kieran - looks like you're having 'one of those' type mondays as well. nice to 'bump' into you again :)

Comment: heh, yeah i'm having one of those really productive days at work.. *cough*

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
preg_match("/\/\*\*(.*?)\*\*\//", $file, $match);
$info = $match[1];
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function find_between($from, $to, $string) {
   $cstring = strstr($string, $from);
   $newstring = substr(substr($cstring, 0, strpos($cstring, $to)), 1);
   return $newstring;
}
```

Then just call: `$comments = find_between('/\*\*', '\*\*/', $myfileline);`