# how to get content from php comment line

Tags: php, wordpress, laravel

my file name is `abc.php`
and

```
<?php
/*
Template Name: mypage
*/
?>
```

so,
how to get `abc.php` nad and my page using `Template Name`.
please help me

Comment: Clear the question! Laravel OR Wordpress?

Comment: any one laravel or wordpress

Comment: Did you want template name while App is run, right?

Comment: yes, i want template name and file name also in array formate or any other like list

Comment: For get the laravel blade name, Place below code inside your filters file:

    View::composer('*', function($view){
     View::share('view_name', $view->getName());
    });

Now in master blade layout file, you can get blade file name via `$view_name` variable.

Answer (score 1):

You can use some custom parser (there are couple available) or reflection , have a look at this:

http://php.net/manual/en/reflectionclass.getdoccomment.php

or as commented in here by svens [PHP read file comments NOT file content - forgotten](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3228978/php-read-file-comments-not-file-content-forgotten)

```
<?php

    $source = file_get_contents( "file.php" );

    $tokens = token_get_all( $source );
    $comment = array(
        T_COMMENT,      // All comments since PHP5
        T_ML_COMMENT,   // Multiline comments PHP4 only
        T_DOC_COMMENT   // PHPDoc comments      
    );
    foreach( $tokens as $token ) {
        if( !in_array($token[0], $comment) )
            break;
        // Do something with the comment
        $txt = $token[1];
    }

?>
```