# How to read document information in php

Tags: php

```
/* ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
-  PHP Version      : 4.0                                                  -
-  This code was created on : 2021/11/29 at 00:10                                  -
-  Checksum                 : d8d8000bfc33a4eba1e6b51b8fc71312                     -
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------- */
```

Hello friends
For example, how to read documentary information
Example: How can I use php to understand what the PHP version says?

Comment: This might help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/708086/how-to-read-comment-blocks-in-php

Comment: This is a non-standard ASCII art comment scheme. You will need a regex to extract any of this. (Finding the comment block is kinda secondary.)

Comment: @Kinglish no it did not work

Comment: @emn, what didn't work? What did you try? I just used the most upvoted answer on that page and [was able](https://3v4l.org/QItc7) to get the entire docblock. Parsing that will still be up to you, however.

Comment: Thankful